# Which variant of base64 encoding is created by Buffer.toString('base64')?

Tags: node.js, base64

In Node.js, it is common to use the built-in `Buffer` to create base64 encoded data:

```
const data = 'Hello world!';
const base64encoded = Buffer.from(data, 'utf8').toString('base64');
console.log(base64encoded); //prints "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh"
```

At the time of writing, [Wikipedia lists no fewer than 14 variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) of base64. However, the [Buffer manual page](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) doesn't specify which variant of base64 is actually used.

Is there any authoritative source that states which variant of base64 is used for encoding in this way?

Comment: In link you provided there is a link to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-5

Comment: @iofjuupasli - yes, but that is only provided in reference to _decoding_, not _encoding_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**:

The [Base64 variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) of [Buffer.toString('base64')](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) is:

> **Base64 standard** [RFC 4648 §4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4)

**Longer answer (why and how)**:

**Why** did I need it?

Recently I also needed to find it out and first search in Google pop-up this post with non-answered question. So here is how I found it and why I needed it in the first place.

Our system communicates with different clients and 3rd party components, which sometimes has a different default Base64 variant, some has `Base64 RFC 2045`, some has `Base64 RFC 4648 §5`, some has `Base64 RFC 4880` and some `Base64 RFC 4648 §4`.

If one side (sender) encodes the data into Base64 with a different variant than the decoding side (receiver) - then the receiving party may get a runtime exception. So I was needed to unify the encoding format through the server.

**How** did I find it?

First thing I did - I checked the source code of the Buffer implementation in hope to find any documented reference in comments. But I didn't find any explicit specification of the variant, it only states it support base64 as one of it's internal `BufferEncoding`.

Second thing I did - I created a small POC on local docker which encodes and decodes all the ASCII chars - and matched the output with all the [table of Base64 variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table)

Here is the code of my Node POC:

```
// Raw bytes for all ASCII from 0 to 127
function dataAscii(){
  const bytes = [];
  for(let i=0; i<127; i++){
    bytes.push(i);
  } 
  return Buffer.from(bytes);
} 

router.get('/base64-check', function(req, res, next) {
  // Encode into base64 using the default variant of NodeJS
  const encodedBase64 = dataAscii().toString('base64');
  // Check if padding with '=' is mandatory or optional
  const noPad = encodedBase64.replace(/=/g, '');
  let optionalPad;
  try{
    Buffer.from(noPad, 'base64').toString('binary');
    optionalPad = true;
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e);
    optionalPad = false;
  }
  res.status(200).send({ encodedBase64, optionalPad });
});
```

The output of this POC is:
[image: Base64 NodeJS Buffer result]

So the only variant from the [table of Base64 variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) that matched this output is the `Base64 RFC 4648 §4`:

[image: Variant conclusion]

Comment: I'd almost forgotten about this question. Nice work!